# What's the most efficient way to calculate the zeros of $f(x) = x^4-x^2-6$?

Tags: calculus, roots, quadratics

How do you calculate the zeros of $f(x) = x^4-x^2-6$ in best way?
Here are my attempts:

Factorize, but the problem is the $6$:

$$0=x^4-x^2-6 \iff 6 = x^2(x^2-1)$$

This doesn't lead to any good solution...

Here is another attempt, but I don't know if this is allowed:

$$0= x^4-x^2-6 \iff 0 = \sqrt{x^4} - \sqrt{x^2} - \sqrt{6}$$

My friend say this no work because I cheat. I Need take minus signs under square root too. Is this tru? If not I can continue this with quadratic equation formula and get the zeroes.

---

Please halp us this is no homework he make this Task because he is curious how is solved and me curious also now. Because our teacher only ask easy Task but we want other Task also because his lesson is always easy but exam is very hard when you compared...

And also pls halp with maths Topic I'm not sure which is corrects.

Comment: set $$x^2=t$$ and solve the quadratic

Comment: But is this no cheat?

Comment: All’s fair in love and mathematics, as long as you tell no lies. You make a temporary substitution, $x^2=t$, to get $t^2-t-6=0$, factor this (easy) to get values of $t$ that make it zero, then take the square roots of these. Two will be imaginary.

Comment: $0=x^4-x^2-6$ is **NOT** equivalent with $\sqrt{x^4}-\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{6}=0$ you can say that $0=\sqrt{x^4-x^2-6}$ but that doesn't lead you anywhere.

Comment: This is not correct:
$$x^4-x^2-6=0 \iff \sqrt{x^4}-\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{6}=0$$
This is like saying that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$, which is obviously incorrect if $a=b=1$.

Comment: Pls no give me negative...

Comment: $x^4-x^2-6=(x^2-3)(x^2+2)$

Comment: Start using your first idea and knowing that $6=3\times 2$. So $x^2=3$ and get two solutions. Calculate other two dividing expression by $x^2-3$. Smart guess sometimes is the most efficient way - however not most general. (Oh, An aedonist was faster, should upvote his answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you got to $x^2 (x^2-1) = 6$ (in plain English, "a number times (itself - $1$) $= 6$), you could have thought that $6 = 3 \cdot 2$ , and conclude in one go, finding the two real roots $\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Had same idea, better to write $6=3 \times 2$ to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

after my hint above we have to solve $$t^2-t-6=0$$ this is $$t_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{24}{4}}$$

Comment: Thank you and all other this is very nice trick I dident know it!!

Answer (score 2):

SUbstitute $x^2=u$ so you get a quadratic equation

$u^2-u-6=0$

then you solve and you get two solutions, one is negative and when you substitute back you have $x^2=negative$ which leads to complex roots

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Solve the equation $(x^2)^2-x^2-6=0$. You will get$$x^2=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{25}}2\iff x^2=3\vee x^2=-2.$$But $x^2$ cannot be $-2$. Therefore, $x^2=3$, and this means that the solutions are $\pm\sqrt3$.

Comment: Are you saying $x=\sqrt{2} i$ and $x=-\sqrt{2} i$  do not satisfy $x^4-x^2-6=0$?

Comment: @Henry No. I just assumed that the OP was working over the real numbers. But, yes, he might be working over the complex numbers. And perhaps even over the quaternions. I really don't know.